# every() method within arrays! New to programming

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods

I'm not understanding why this doesn't work

```
function every(arr, callback) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (callback(arr[i]) === true) {
            return true
        }else return false
    }
}
```

can someone help me understand how the every() method works. I need to write the source code itself for the method in relation to the following 2 questions.

```
describe('every', function () {
        it('returns true when the callback returns true for all elements', function () {
            const original = ['ace', 'cat', 'dog', 'pit']
            const result = every(original, (el) => el.length === 3)
            expect(result).to.be.true
        })

        it("returns false when the callback doesn't return true for all elements", function () {
            const original = ['ace', 'cat', 'parrot', 'dog']
            const result = every(original, (el) => el.length === 3)
            expect(result).to.be.false
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only testing the first element of the array, because you return either true or false inside the loop.

You should return `false` immediately if the test fails. Otherwise, you need to keep looping. If you get through the entire loop, then you can return `true`.

```js
function every(arr, callback) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!callback(arr[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ok that does help me a lot! I'm still not 100% on why the "!" allows this.

Comment: `!` means "NOT", it's like `if (callback(arr[i]) == false)`

Comment: ah ok ok.. so it's like 'if the callback returns false while looping, then return false... where as I was ending it in the array upon the first boolean response. ok man thank you so much, i'm 4 weeks of studying in now, still getting it

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote: "return false immediately if the test fails, otherwise keep looping"